# Combine Stack Navigator with Bottom Tab Navigator on React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I want to know how to combine bottom tab navigator with Stack Navigator on Home Navigator in app.js
Here is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';
import Signup from './screens/signup';
import Login from './screens/login';
import Home from './screens/Home';
import Loading from './screens/Loading';
import Welcome from './screens/Welcome';
import ForgotPassword from './screens/ForgotPassword';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <AppContainer />;
  }
}

const navigator = createStackNavigator({
  loading: {
    screen: Loading,
    navigationOptions: {
      headerShown: false,
      headerTransparent: true,
    },
  },
  Welcome: {
    screen: Welcome,
    navigationOptions: {
      headerShown: false,
      headerTransparent: true,
    },
  },
  signup: {
    screen: Signup,
    navigationOptions: {
      headerShown: false,
      headerTransparent: true,
    },
  },
  login: {
    screen: Login,
    navigationOptions: {
      headerShown: false,
      headerTransparent: true,
    },
  },
  Home: {
    screen: Home,
    navigationOptions: {
      headerShown: false,
      headerTransparent: true,
    },
  },
  InitialRouteName: Loading,
});

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(navigator);
```

Any suggest to add bottom tab navigator in this code? I want to know how to combine Tab bottom navigator with stack navigator in app.js (calling home with bottom tab navigator)
thanks

Comment: You can create a bottomtabnavigator and set it to any stack screen

Comment: can you give me the example on answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a tabNavigator and set it like any other route.

Obs: Also work for drawerNavigator.

Example:

```
const MainTab = TabNavigator(tabs, {
  initialRouteName: initialRouteName,
  tabBarPosition: "bottom",
});


const RootNavigator = StackNavigator(
  {
    Root: {
      screen: MainTab,
      navigationOptions: {
        headerMode: "none"
      }
    },
    /* Other Screens */
    Login: { screen: LoginScreen },
  }
)

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(RootNavigator);
```

Obs: this also work for drawerNavigator.

Comment: thank you for your answer. which one i need to import with bottom tabs navigator?

Comment: You can read this here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-based-navigation/ 

Or see in oficial page: 
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/